# How Do I Fix My YouTube Embedded Code In Brackets So That Live Preview Will Work?

Tags: html, css, github, iframe, youtube

So basically I recently made a video for a assignment and I copied the embedded code from You tube and  pasted it in Brackets.io and after I clicked save and then pressed live preview it didn't work and when I went to the website that shows you the many reasons why live preview won't work one of  those reasons was

*"Bug #7935: Live CSS does not update if page contains an iframe (including injected iframes such as ads or social media buttons)."*

So how do I fix this?

If Anyone knows please reply back to me!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use for embedding a video a kind of code like this:

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

I usually use this for holding videos in my webs, so if this still gives you problems, you should use another editor, maybe Visual Studio Code and install an extension call Live Server by Ritwick Dey, which does the same as Bracket's Live Preview.

Comment: Thank You So Much Nelson I will definitely try that and hopefully it will it work!